# Register confidential OIDC client through registration endpoint

Tags: keycloak

I would like to programmatically register confidential OIDC client (the client is a backend service). I checked the keycloak [document](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/client-registration.html) about it. And I use the “Initial access token“ approach as recommended.

After I created a "initial access token" on the UI console, I register a new client by:

```
POST https://my-keycloak-host/auth/realms/MyRealm/clients-registrations/default

Headers: Authorization: Bearer <initial access token>

{ "clientId": "my-client" }
```

The response contains a `registrationAccessToken`. But I expect to get a client secret. How can I get it? And what is the usage for that `registrationAccessToken`?

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason Keycloak doesn't set secret properly. But you can define own secret with `secret` property in the payload (tested with Keycloak 16.1.1), e.g.:

```
{ 
"clientId": "my-client",
"secret": "my-secret"
}
```

Doc:

- https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html
- https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_client_registration